# button that is just text in action bar

Tags: android

I was wondering if you can just put plain text as a button in the action bar. I was messing around with a spinner, but i just dont really care for how it looks, but I do like how it says something instead of a picture (icon). I dont really like how its forced on the lfet side of the action bar by my icon.

Can i just make a 'button' that says options that I can make appear on the right side. In one of my other apps I did this on the right side, but it was just using an icon as a menu. Can you use a text button as a menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `android:icon` attribute from your menu XML :

```
<item android:id="@+id/my_id"
          android:title="@string/my_string"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

Or try to use the `Icon Generator` from [here](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html), chose the `Text` tab and generate your icons with the provided text.

Comment: could this possibly not be working due to having a 'theme' on the actionbar? i made the actionbar white so it matches my app, but what you said to do to get the button to show is not working?

Answer (score 1):

In your `menu.xml`, you simply remove the `android:icon="@drawable/ic_someicon"` entry. This means that the Action Bar entry becomes whatever is in the `android:title="@string/some_menu_title"` attribute instead; that is, it becomes a button with text rather than a button with an icon.

Comment: could this possibly not be working due to having a 'theme' on the actionbar? i made the actionbar white so it matches my app, but what you said to do to get the button to show is not working?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by 'not working'? Was the button showing up with an icon before?

Comment: nevermind it works. I just had onCreateOptionsMenu commented out for some stupid reason.

Comment: Haha, yep, that'll break menu inflation.